# Android Xamarin AndroidX.Room metadata usage

Tags: xamarin.android, android-room

Ive been trying to use the AndroidX Room library to interface with an SQLite db but have had a variety of issues with the metadata tags. Ive found a variety of resources and samples for the java library, but none for the c# implementation. Here is the official [Room documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data).

The issue is I am getting Errors for the metadata tags 'Database' and 'TypeConverters', namely:

```
Error   CS0655  'Value' is not a valid named attribute argument because it is not a valid attribute parameter type
Error   CS0655  'Entities' is not a valid named attribute argument because it is not a valid attribute parameter type
```

My class model is pretty simple:

```
[Entity]
public class ItemRecord
{
    [PrimaryKey(AutoGenerate = true)]
    private int uid { get; set; }
    public string ItemStyle { get; private set; }
    public string ItemBrand { get; private set; }
}
```

And my room implementation is nothing special, similiar to most of the examples out there for java adapted for c#

```
enum OnConflictEnum : int
{
    REPLACE = 1,
    ROLLBACK,
    ABORT,
    FAIL,
    IGNORE
};

class DateConverter
{
    [TypeConverter]
    public static DateTime toDate(long timestamp)
    {
        return new DateTime(timestamp);
    }

    [TypeConverter]
    public static long toTimestamp(DateTime date)
    {
        return date.Ticks;
    }
}

[Dao]
public abstract class ItemModelDao
{
    [Query(Value = "select * from items_db")]
    public abstract List<ItemRecord> GetAllProducts();

    [Query(Value = "select * from items_db where itemId = :itemId")]
    public abstract ItemRecord GetProductById(int itemId);

    [Insert(OnConflict = (int)OnConflictEnum.REPLACE)]
    public abstract void AddProduct(ItemRecord item);

    [Update(OnConflict = (int)OnConflictEnum.REPLACE)]
    public abstract void UpdateProduct(ItemRecord item);

    [Delete]
    public abstract void DeleteProduct(ItemRecord item);
}

[Database(Entities = ItemRecord, Version = 1)]
[TypeConverters(Value = typeof(ItemRecord) )]
public abstract class AppDataBase : RoomDatabase
{
    private int[] myarr = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    private const string dbName = "items_db";
    private static AppDataBase INSTANCE;

    public static AppDataBase getDatabase(Context context)
    {
        if (INSTANCE == null)
        {
            INSTANCE = (AppDataBase)Room.DatabaseBuilder(context, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(AppDataBase)), dbName).Build();
        }  
        return INSTANCE;
    }  

    public static void destroyInstance()
    {
        INSTANCE = null;
    }
    public abstract ItemModelDao ItemModel();  
}
```

Any suggestions or resources would be appreciated.

Comment: For the error message, please check if the 'Entities' and `Value` field is a valid attribute parameter type in source code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0655

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think I've read this before but partly misinterpreted it. The 'Value' attribute is defined as public with a getter and setter but the type is of Java.Lang.Class, which from your link suggests is 'not a valid attribute'. So how do I set that meta data?

Comment: Try to delete the `Value`. Is there any `Entities` you have set?

Comment: If you delete the `Value` you lose that piece of metadata and the library cant see that class to add it as a table. Notice the `ItemRecord` class has an entity metadata tag. It looks to me as though the java library has not been correctly binded to xamarin. The Value attribute is of type Java.Lang.Class which is not a primitive type, which should not be in the metadata.. yet the library is designed for it to be.

Comment: In fact Ive just found the github repo for the project and there is an open bug for it [here](https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/issues/77). Personally I've moved on to use sqlite-net-pcl as my database ORM